# Unable to extract Animal name from the File Path using 'rfind' function

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Unable to extract Animal name from the file path using `rfind` function.

Animal name will be used as the key in dictionary `index = {}`

My png file path is: `c:\users\intel\desktop\folder\elephant.png`

After running this code,

```
import ZernikeMoments
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cPickle
import glob
import cv2


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-a", "--animals", required = True,
    help = "Path where the animals will be stored")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--index", required = True,
    help = "Path to where the index file will be sotred")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


desc = ZernikeMoments(21)
index = {}

for animalPath in glob.glob(args["animals"] + "/*.png"):
    # parse out the name, load image and convert to grayscale
    animal = animalPath[animalPath.rfind("/") + 1: ].replace(".png", "")
    image = cv2.imread(animalPath, 0)

    image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, 15, 15, 15, 15,
        cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = 255)
    thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
    thresh[thresh > 0] = 255

    outline = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype = "uint8")
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    cv2.drawContours(outline, [cnts], -1, 255, -1)

    moments = desc.describe(outline)
    index[animal] = moments
```

I get `c:\users\intel\desktop\folder\elephant` as the dictionary key.
The aim is to get dictionary key as `elephant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `ntpath`

```
import ntpath
a_path = "c:\users\intel\desktop\folder\elephant.png"
>>>ntpath.basename(a_path)
'elephant.png'
>>>ntpath.basename(a_path).split(".")[0]
'elephant'
```

OR simply using `ntpath` and `os`

```
>>>os.path.splitext(ntpath.basename(a_path))[0]
'elephant'
```

Comment: Awesome @itzmeontv !
Thanks for the useful input. Short and simple..and it works

Comment: @patrick.c you really should not use `ntpath`  module unless you specifically want to work with windows paths on linux or mac. `os.path` is guaranteed to be the path module suitable for OS python is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.basename` function

```
animal =  os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(animalPath))[0]
```

Do not forget to import `os` module

Comment: I see, didnt know about that. Alrite @Alik i'll take note of that, thanks for putting down such helpful comment!